# What classes should be included in a "restart the human race" curriculum?

Tags: post-apocalypse, science-in-society, population, post-scarcity

I've mostly written a story from the point of view of filler programs in an online university, the characters initially existed to put human students at ease in RV classrooms with greatly diminished attendance. The programs grew so they could also fill an exposition role where students were missing certain aspects of the classes etc... In the end these programs got very close to human in their complexity and individuality but they still exist to take classes. Anyway now there aren't any humans left, almost, there is at least one possibly several people still around but they refuse to interact with the fillers so there are classes that these humans are taking that the fillers can't access. This person or persons is trying to get the human race back up and working.

The problem I'm having is this; apart from [parthenogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis), [cloning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning), and [demography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demography) what other subjects should they be studying? Also any pointers on the structure of university level biology in the Ivy-league from a student perspective instead of a prospectus would be of use.

Notes to help limit subjects a little, the human race basically went extinct through apathy after we stopped being involved in any of the basic or advanced stages of producing our own material culture. All of the needs, and most of the wants, of any survivor can be meet at the push of a button but I'm presuming that the task ahead will require novel devices and have included some classes in programming [Cornucopia Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_assembler), anything else in terms of "basic life-skills" that you feel isn't covered will be considered but aren't hugely relevant. Assume that the human protagonist has a solid secondary school education in math and the sciences. Mainly I'm looking for advanced subjects in Biology that are relevant to trying to bring the human race back from the brink and any really left-field things that I haven't thought of like do I need to include classes in linear math before certain other subjects are going to make sense, that sort of thing.

Please note, there are no humans in this story, whatsoever just the spectre of closed classes as someone tries to work out the seemingly impossible.

Comment: Your humanity needs motivational speakers more than science classes.

Comment: @Alexander The few that are left seem to be motivated enough that their going to try a major restoration project, I think they're covered. Whether they succeed or fail is kind of immaterial to the story though.

Comment: What you need is a law or enforcement of some type that forces them to reproduce in order to have access to that magic button. The "if you can make a baby and raise him, we'll give you access to the magic button when he's older than X years old" kinda thing. If the human race is apathetic enough to go extinct because of that button, the human race will be just as apathetic when it comes to learning, and won't actually learn anything regardless of what you put in the curriculum

Comment: @Aify Irrelevant.

Comment: @Ash Hence comment, not answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sorts of engineering. If people are going to re-take control of the machines, they have to know how they work.

Science. You need some science to understand engineering, and if people are going to get on the road to progress again you need in depth science. If human population has dwindled to the point of near extinction, biology might be the most important science. But if the problem is not biological, i.e. it's not that people are incapable of reproducing and thriving, but that they have lost interest in doing so, then biology is not the pre-eminent issue.

History, philosophy, and religion. If people have lost interest in preserving society, you need to give them reasons to change their minds. They have to have reasons to think that human life has value and is worth preserving.

And of course the real essentials: feminist theory, oppression studies, etc.

Comment: You make a valid point, one I don't think the humans involved would actually grasp but useful nonetheless.

Comment: You don't need engineering when you have [Smart Fog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_fog) only programming.

Comment: I'd presume that reliance on technology without knowing how to rebuild it, from scratch, would be a reason why civilization would collapse. :-)

Comment: Civilisation didn't collapse though, just the human population, civilisation is alive and kicking, and mystified by the class choices of the human(s) knocking around the place.

Answer (score 5):

I am not a specialist in biology, so, unfortunately, I cannot point you to the most relevant fields for your humanity restoration project. I hope someone else will be more helpful with this.

With this said, I think that biology no matter how advanced is not an answer to your problem. It will treat the symptoms, true, but it will not deal with the cause of the problem. Thus, there is a possibility that the situation will become only worse. I suggest you start looking in a different direction first.

Since you are stating that

> the human race basically went extinct through apathy

you need an army of psychologists to treat what looks like a widespread [depression](https://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/publications/depression/index.shtml). Without addressing this condition first, most of your other efforts will be in vain. People with depression are not necessarily suicidal or constantly sad, but they often lack motivation and energy to do 'external' things. Their focus tends to be entirely on their own condition and sufferings (which can manifest as emptiness and indecisiveness as opposed to popularised in films extremely low moods and rivers of tears).

Considering that

> All of the needs, and most of the wants, of any survivor can be meet at the push of a button

immediate biological survival is not a problem. There is also no need for re-industrialisation or bootstrapping technology. Your main priority is to get people motivated, organised, willing to learn, and eventually to reproduce. Therefore, **the most important classes at this stage will be psychology, psychological counselling, psychotherapy, psychiatry, and psychopharmacology.** Introducing these into your curriculum and focusing them on treating depression spectrum disorders will produce much-needed specialists. It might take about a decade to see the first results. But you can expect some new vigour in your survivors.

I would also suggest adding counselling features to your filler programmes. Depending on human-filler relationships it might be harder for fillers to get through to humans. But unlike humans, programmes are very persistent (or can be made so), so, eventually, they will make some progress with at least a small number of students. For some people, a virtual counsellor might be a preferred option due to greater confidentiality and perceived objectivity and lack of judgement. So, you might consider programming and training virtual psychologists as well.

Once you have psychological counselling up and running, I would suggest reviving old university curricula and offer a wide selection of classes in all disciplines. Get people access to as many fields as they wish to study. Discourage very narrow specialisations and encourage broad education at least in the first 5-6 years of post-secondary education. Familiarity with other fields of study helps to come up with novel approaches and solutions to existing problems.

I also think that if possible school programmes should be changed to include more art, music, and physical education classes. All these activities are effective deterrents of depressive conditions. I also believe that your society needs art more than science because it lost its interest in life. Cloning will not solve this.

Philosophy, sociology, legal and political sciences might become necessary if you go the cloning route. You will have to solve existential problems (such as whether clones have souls or not), social problems (overcome an aversion to clones if any already exists), and legal problems (identification, inheritance, parental/child rights, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

**History and anthropology** will be paramount. They would not be the first civilization to collapse, and will likely not be the last. History can show you how problems were solved without current tech, **the history of technology is basically half of a "how to rebuild civilization" guide.** The other half being history of culture and philosophy. Even recent (for us) history will be helpful, like how the cavendish banana went extinct becasue they were all clones and one disease wiped them out. history can introduce a very wide range of subjects very quickly.

Paleontology AKA the history of life would be nice addition, they will deal with concepts of deep time, long reaching consequences, accumulation of collective action, and complex interactions which will be important.

Finding out oxygen was a deadly waste produced in minute quantities by oceans full of bacteria that nearly caused the extinction of all life is good for reminding people small actions by lots of people can have huge cumulative effects. It is also a nice lesson since they nearly drove themselves to extinction.

**Evolutionary psychology** will be nice as well, why humans do some of the weird self-destructive things we do will help understand what happened and how to avoid it, and possibly even how to change it.

Keep in mind motivation will be a real issue for survivors since their wants and needs will be met, and humans can be breathtakingly lazy under these conditions.   Long time scale thinking skills, debate, and exploration will help combat this.

**Maker and artistic skills**, as strange as it sounds this will be very important. The desire to build and create thing for the sheer pleasure of it will go a long way to keeping people motivated and to keep them human and creative. This also teaches the single biggest skill set they will need, **problem solving skills**. It is also a good way to combat depression which will be rampant. Plus all the theoretical knowledge in the world will not help if you don't know how to put it in practice, your people need lots of practice in building and creating.